# hlineHow to add a vertical dashed line to a time series graph?

Tags: r, time-series

My data is like this:

```
Day              my_variable
2022-02-10         1.21
2022-02-11         1.35
2022-02-12         1.43
2022-02-13         1.58
2022-02-14         1.11
2022-02-15         1.78
2022-02-16         1.34
2022-02-17         1.75
```

I use the following code to create a descriptive time-series graph:

```
ts_plot(mydata,
        title = "my graph",
        Xtitle = "Day",
        Ytitle = "my variable")
```

I want to add a vertical dashed line for 2022-02-13. I tried it with `geom_vline(xintercept= '2022-02-13', linetype="dashed")` and `abline(v=as.Date("2022-02-13"))`   but didn't work.

Comment: Which package? There are multiple `ts_plot` funcs out there ...

Comment: If this is base graphics, try `abline(v=...)`. If `ggplot2`-based, then `geom_vline(yintercept=...)`

Comment: if using `ggplot2` and depending on your Day format, you may need to wrap with `as.Date(...)`.  Code would be `geom_vline(yintercept = as.Date(...), ...)`